# UI Router 2 not waiting for subscription to resolve before resolving

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui router in an angular 5 app.  I'm trying to make a call to the backend and wait for that to resolve before loading the component for that route.  However, the component keeps loading before the resolve finishes.   Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
{
  name: 'brochure',
  url: '/brochure/{propertyId}',
  component: PropertyBrochureComponent,
  resolve: [
     {
      token: 'brochureResponse',
      useFactory: (trans, dataService: MyDataService) => {
          dataService.send(new BrochureRequest(trans.params().propertyId)).subscribe((data) => {
              return data;
          });
      },
      deps: [Transition, MyDataService]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Where is the service? I suspect it's using a Subscription (asynchronous) and you need to use a promise.

Comment: try setting `return` before the `dataService.send()` function, i.e. `return dataService.send(....`.